# How to recursively query for many to many relationships in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, recursive-query

I have a table in SQL 2012 that has a many to many relationship with itself through a junction table.  It's laid out as follows

[image]

The many to many relationship I'm referring to is Currency_Dependency.

What I would like to do is make a recursive query that displays all dependencies in a tree fashion, so that each relationship is denoted with a number that shows how many steps away from the primary currency item being selected, as well as a number identifying which branch it's on.  I would want, if possible, this query to go both ways, showing all of the currency items it depends on (Parent currency items), as well as all of the currency items that depend on it (child currency items).  I have a query that shows only the first level both ways.

```
SELECT curr.Model AS 'Root Currency Item', cur2.Model AS 'Child Currency Item', cur3.Model AS 'Parent Currency Item'
FROM dbo.Currency curr
FULL JOIN dbo.Currency_Dependency cdep
ON curr.CurrencyId = cdep.CurrencyId
FULL JOIN dbo.Currency cur2
ON cdep.DependencyId = cur2.CurrencyId
FULL JOIN dbo.Currency_Dependency cdep2
ON curr.CurrencyId = cdep2.DependencyId
FULL JOIN dbo.Currency cur3
ON cdep2.CurrencyId = cur3.CurrencyId
WHERE curr.Status = 1 AND NOT(cur2.Model IS null AND cur3.Model IS null)
```

Which produces these results

[image]

So I would like additional columns for parent and child dependencies with that number denoting how many steps from the root currency item it is.  I hope that makes sense.

Is such a query possible?  I'm aware that a common table expression is something that is used for recursive queries but everything I've read on it so far has been pretty Greek (I'm a 2nd year Computer programming student)

Please let me know if you can help!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without example data I can't be sure, but I think this is what you are after:

```
;with cte as (
-- anchor elements: where curr.Status = 1 and not a dependent
  select 
      CurrencyId
    , Model
    , ParentId     = null
    , ParentModel  = convert(varchar(128),'')
    , Root         = curr.Model
    , [Level]      = convert(int,0)
    , [Path]       = convert(varchar(512),Model)
  from dbo.Currency as curr  
  where curr.Status = 1
    /* anchors do not depend on any other currency */
    and not exists (
      select 1 
      from dbo.Currency_Dependency i
      where curr.CurrencyId = i.DependencyId
      )
  -- recursion begins here
  union all 
  select 
      CurrencyId   = c.CurrencyId
    , Model        = c.Model
    , ParentId     = p.CurrencyId
    , ParentModel  = convert(varchar(128),p.Model)
    , Root         = p.Root
    , [Level]      = p.[Level] + 1
    , [Path]       = convert(varchar(512),p.[Path] + ' > ' + c.Model)
  from dbo.Currency as c
    inner join dbo.Currency_Dependency as dep
      on c.CurrencyId = dep.DependencyId
    inner join cte as p 
      on dep.CurrencyId = p.CurrencyId
)
select * from cte
```

Comment: Wow, Brilliant!  Thank you so much!